# How to read/decode temporary function names of list comprehension in Erlang when debugging

Tags: debugging, erlang, list-comprehension

When debugging a module (e.g. `foo`) with list comprehensions temporary function names e.g.

```
foo:'-loop/4-lc$^2/1-3-'
```

can be found in trace output or error messages.  If many list comprehensions are in a module its often hard to find out which one is running.

How can the function name be interpreted?

What are the meaning of the call parameters of these functions?

What is the meaning of the return value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fields can be described as follows:

```
foo:'-loop/4-lc$^2/1-3-'
^     ^    ^ ^   ^ ^ ^
1     2    3 4   5 6 7
```

1. Module name
2. The enclosing function
3. Arity of the enclosing function
4. The type of fun (`lc` = list generator in a list comprehension, `blc` = binary generator in a list comprehension, `lbc` = list generator in a binary comprehension, `fun` = fun)
5. Index of function within defining function (0 based)
6. Arity of the generated function
7. Index of lambda lifted function within defining function

Open questions: what is the meaning of the parameters and return values of these functions?

Just stumbled on [this answer by Robert Virding](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2010-February/049493.html) to the same question on the erlang-questions Mailinglist.

---

The code which creates these names is spread among many modules: `sys_pre_expand` for funs; `v3_core` for functions created for comprehensions; and `v3_kernel` which adds more when lambda lifting the functions. The goal of all this is to create "unique" function names which also give some indication of why the functions were created and why.

In [`sys_pre_expand.erl`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/dev/lib/compiler/src/sys_pre_expand.erl#L546) there is code fore creating function names for funs:

```
%% new_fun_name(State) -> {FunName,State}.

new_fun_name(#expand{func=F,arity=A,fcount=I}=St) ->
    Name = "-" ++ atom_to_list(F) ++ "/" ++ integer_to_list(A)
        ++ "-fun-" ++ integer_to_list(I) ++ "-",
    {list_to_atom(Name),St#expand{fcount=I+1}}.
```

These names are passed on and expanded in a later pass (v3_kernel).

From the compilers [`v3_core.erl`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/dev/lib/compiler/src/v3_core.erl#L1533):

```
%% new_fun_name(Type, State) -> {FunName,State}.

new_fun_name(Type, #core{fcount=C}=St) ->
    {list_to_atom(Type ++ "$^" ++ integer_to_list(C)),St#core{fcount=C+1}}.
```

So this accounts for the "lc$^2" (parts 4 and 5) in the example. When looking at the places where it is used the possible values for part 4 can be deduced: `lc`, `blc` and `lbc`.

In [`v3_kernel.erl`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/dev/lib/compiler/src/v3_kernel.erl#L757) is the next phase when these functions are lambda lifted:

```
%% new_fun_name(Type, State) -> {FunName,State}.

new_fun_name(Type, #kern{func={F,Arity},fcount=C}=St) ->
    Name = "-" ++ atom_to_list(F) ++ "/" ++ integer_to_list(Arity) ++
    "-" ++ Type ++ "-" ++ integer_to_list(C) ++ "-",
    {list_to_atom(Name),St#kern{fcount=C+1}}.
```

This accounts for `-loop/4-` (parts 2 and 3) and `-3-` (part 7). Part 6 is added in the call to this `new_fun_name/2`.

---

(This post is a community wiki, please add the other entries if you know what they mean)

Comment: If funs in general are included in the description above, `fun` is a valid type (try crashing inside a normal fun).