# How to interpret the results of trace info in erlang program?

Tags: function, erlang, trace

## This is the program

```
-module(fun_param).

-export([start/0, partition_parallel/2]).

partition_parallel(F, Es) ->
    Parent = self(),
    Running = [{spawn_monitor(fun() -> Parent ! {self(), F(E)} end), E, helloworld} || E <- Es].


start()->
   partition_parallel(
       fun (C) ->
           io:format("hello:~p~n", [C])
       end, [1,2,3]).
```

## And trace the program using recon_trace

```
recon_trace:calls({fun_param, '_', fun(_) -> return_trace() end}, 2000, [return_to, {scope, local}]).
```

## There are some outputs I do not understand.

```
4:22:12.026917 <0.161.0> fun_param:'-partition_parallel/2-lc$^0/1-0-'([1,2,3], #Fun<fun_param.0.111727472>, <0.161.0>)

4:22:12.027101 <0.161.0> fun_param:'-partition_parallel/2-lc$^0/1-0-'([2,3], #Fun<fun_param.0.111727472>, <0.161.0>)

4:22:12.027327 <0.161.0> fun_param:'-partition_parallel/2-lc$^0/1-0-'([3], #Fun<fun_param.0.111727472>, <0.161.0>)

4:22:12.027475 <0.161.0> fun_param:'-partition_parallel/2-lc$^0/1-0-'([], #Fun<fun_param.0.111727472>, <0.161.0>)

4:22:12.027581 <0.161.0> fun_param:'-partition_parallel/2-lc$^0/1-0-'/3 --> []

4:22:12.027704 <0.161.0>  '--> fun_param:'-partition_parallel/2-lc$^0/1-0-'/3
```

- What does this mean
  `'-partition_parallel/2-lc$^0/1-0-'`, especially `lc$^0/1` ?
- What does these parameters comes from ?

```
 ([1,2,3], #Fun<fun_param.0.111727472>, <0.161.0>)
```

Comment: This is similar to this [How to read/decode temporary function names of list comprehension in Erlang when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019447/how-to-read-decode-temporary-function-names-of-list-comprehension-in-erlang-when)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/decode temporary function names of list comprehension in Erlang when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019447/how-to-read-decode-temporary-function-names-of-list-comprehension-in-erlang-when)

Comment: It's enough, though not very accurate and precise.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```erlang
'-partition_parallel/2-lc$^0/1-0-'
```

Is very well described by this post:
[How to read/decode temporary function names of list comprehension in Erlang when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019447/how-to-read-decode-temporary-function-names-of-list-comprehension-in-erlang-when)

The arguments

```erlang
([1,2,3], #Fun<fun_param.0.111727472>, <0.161.0>)
```

break down as follows:

- `[1,2,3]` the arguments passed to the anonymous function
- `#Fun<fun_param.0.111727472>` the compiled anonymous function defined in `partition_parallel`
- `<0.161.0>` the pid for the process executing the function